# В PyCharm файл .png открывается с ошибкой

Tags: python, pycharm

В PyCharm файл .png открывается с ошибкой:
'file was loaded in the wrong encoding: 'UTF-8'
Соответственно, картинка не отображается.

Comment: файл .png в рабочем проекте? путь в настройках проекта включает директорию с изображением?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153703/file-was-loaded-in-the-wrong-encodingutf-8-in-intellij-idea  -  возможно поможет

Comment: В общем дело было так: файл с кодом, который создавал этот Png файл был создан в папке scratches. При попытке открыть файл система выдавала вышеописанную ошибку. Ваш вопрос навел меня на мысль создать файл с кодом в папке проекта и все заработало.